# How do I access my Virtualbox using Vagrant on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, virtualbox

Steps I have done so far:
I have downloaded VirtualBOx and VagrantOn my Windows7
On my local machine I made a directory in C: drive -> mkdir SitesVM
at the Windows command line CD'ed to SitesVM and did 
      vagrant init
      vagrant up 
      vagrant ssh

This is what popped up

```
C:\SitesVM>vagrant ssh
ssh executable not found in any directories in the %PATH% variable. Is an
SSH client installed? Try installing Cygwin, MinGW or Git, all of which
contain an SSH client. Or use your favorite SSH client with the following
authentication information shown below:

Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 2222
Username: vagrant
Private key: C:/SitesVM/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

I have Installed CYGWIN as suggested, but Cygwin must not be communicating locally because it does not have any files available through Cygwin command line.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cygwin tools (like `ssh`) will work from the Cygwin command line, but not a Windows command line.

Do a `vagrant destroy` or at least a `vagrant suspend` from the Window command line where you are currently working. Then try starting up a Cygwin Terminal, change to the same directory (`cd /cygdrive/c/SitesVM`) and then start the VM again from there (`vagrant up`).

Now, you should be able to use `vagrant ssh` from the Cygwin bash shell.

(Not all of this is strictly necessary, but it will make it easier to continue working from the bash shell.)

If it still doesn't work, then SSH may not be installed.

From the Cygwin command line, type `ssh`. You should see:

```
$ ssh
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

if the Cygwin SSH client is installed properly.

If it says `-bash: ssh: command not found`, go into the Cygwin installer (`setup-x86.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe`) and in the Select Packages screen, search for `openssh`. Switch that from `Skip` to a version (right now `6.8p1-1`) and hit Next. That will install the `ssh` client in Cygwin.

Comment: Looks like things are moving in the right direction. After running  vagrant up ithen immediately ran vagrant ssh and get the following ssh executable not found just as noted above. any suggestions ?

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. How in the world would I have figured that out on my own ?!?!?!?!?